# Configuring .htaccess subpath before domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I'm trying to accomplish something:
I've example.com as domain and example.com/subpath, whenever you land in example.com/subpath and click on nodes, it'll be example.com/subpath/node.
I need to write a rule in the .htaccess so that when the user land on the subpath the url will become like:
subpath.example.com/node

Any advice? 
I was thinking using a variable but not really confident with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rewrite rule. Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

DirectoryIndex                                      page/index.html //first page

RewriteRule ^node$                              

subpath/node.php [QSA,L]
```